# Working with pop-up window (Appium, Safary, iOS)

Tags: safari, automation, popup, appium

I'm doing some automation testing for Safari. By using Appium, Nighwatch.JS (Node.JS).
Currently, I have a trouble with the pop-up window.

Maybe someone have met it before and know how to deal with it.
According to [this](https://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/migrating-to-xcuitest/) doc, the capabilities autoAcceptAlerts and autoDismissAlerts do not currently work.

[Open a pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw6xe.png)

On my previous project, I had similar issue and resolved it with org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.java.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include what you have tried so far?

Comment: Since popups are always in the  same location you could use a tap/press on a certain coordinate to accept/deny the popup.

Comment: @ChukUltima maybe not if screen size and device orientation can vary.